# How do I bound $\int_{\gamma_{R}}\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)}dx$ where $\gamma_R$ is a half circle on the upper half plane, so that it vanishes?

Tags: complex-analysis

I get $\int_{\gamma_{R}}\frac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)}dx$=$\int^\pi_0 \frac{sin(Re^{i\theta})}{Re^{i\theta}(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$

so
$\mid \int^\pi_0 \frac{sin(Re^{i\theta})}{Re^{i\theta}(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}d\theta\mid\leq \int^\pi_0 \mid \frac{sin(Re^{i\theta})}{Re^{i\theta}(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}\mid d\theta
$

Then I tried to simplify the integrand. I get

$\mid \frac{sin(Re^{i\theta})}{Re^{i\theta}(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}\mid=\mid\frac{e^{iRcos\theta-Rsin\theta}-e^{-iRcos\theta+Rsin\theta}}{2(1+R^2e^{2i\theta})}\mid$, and when I send $R\to \infty$, I can't bound this term to make it zero. Can you please explain where I did wrong? Or, is there any simpler way to do this so that this integral vanishes as $R$ goes to infinity? I've seen an argument using big $O$ but I really don't understand.

Comment: You're right that $\sin z$ is unbounded on the upper half plane. The fix is to use $\sin z = \operatorname{Im} e^{iz}$ and then take the line integrals on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It is better if you consider
$
\dfrac{\sin x}{x(1+x^2)} = \dfrac{\Im e^{ix} }{x(1+x^2)}
$
and work with $f(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)}$.  You just need to show that

$$
\left|\dfrac{1}{z (1+z^2)}\right| \leq \frac{M}{R^k}, k > 1.
$$

Comment: I think I see it now, using $e^{iz}$ and doing the same thing as above. But I don't quite see how the inequality you give me is useful.

Comment: Why is there 1 on the numerator? Because $\mid e^{iz}\mid$ is not 1.

Comment: Ohh ok I'm confused now. I did find that if I substitute with $e^{iz}$, the integration vanishes, but maybe it's not enough..

Comment: I understand it now, thank you. It's because $|e^{iz}|$ is less than 1 on the upper half plane. Just making sure, it also makes sense when $k=1$ in your inequality, right?